# Can I make Bixby to play a music in Bixby Studio?

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

One of my favorite commands for Bixby is to play a song. Then, Bixby plays music using 'Melon' app that I set as the default player. Melon is a music streaming service like Spotify, so it plays songs not downloading music files.

Recently I'm working on music recommendation app and I want to make Bixby capsule for it. Can I use this 'Play a music' command in capsule development? For example, if I know the title of the song and the artist's name, can I make my capsule play the song using default player of my phone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can definitely do this!

This is one of the use cases for which the `app-launch` functionality ([documentation](https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/reference/type/result-view.app-launch)) exists.

Please explore the design guide ([documentation](https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/dev-guide/design-guides/design-principles.app-punch-out-policies)) regarding when it is okay to use this functionality and when it is not to ensure that your users have the best experience when using your capsule.